# How to run a basic Python script on azure for save data in a db

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-runbook

I would like to run a python script on Azure that connects to an Azure bus queue and saves the data to a database. I installed my script on an Azure service plan app but the script runs only when I am connected by ssh to the app (why?). I have seen many posts that recommend to either use azure functions (but they are triggered by ssh requests which is not my case) or to use runbooks but I have no idea how it works and if I can use that for my case. Do you have any advice?

- What should I use between app, functions or runbook?

or

- how can I make my script work even when I don't have an ssh connection with my app?
  Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Looking into your scenario, Runbook is the best option. Basically it will be under Azure Automation account. Please find the reference link for Runbook. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/start-runbooks

Comment: Thanks for your help !
I'm looking for that solution.

For whose who have the same problem as me for the Azure app services, it's should be because I use a free version so the service "Always On" can't be switched on... To change that I have to update my subscription from F1:Free to something else.